# How to insert in a table in which trigger is also present?

Tags: oracle, triggers, procedure

For the past few days, I am working on my SQL project 'Supermarket Billing Management System', here I am getting a lot of obstacles while creating this project. Since I am a beginner I am not able to solve my all issues, So please help me!!
Here is my doubt:
I have created a table called 'Payments' and inside it, I have even created a trigger and a procedure, Now I don't know how to insert the values in the Payments table because of trigger and procedure. And I want such a procedure that can add the total of the product's price of a single person and it will store into Final Total, I am not sure that my procedure code is right or not, but it was created successfully. So if there is any problem with my Procedure code then please let me know and please also tell me how can I insert it by giving an example

Paymnets table :

```
create table Paymnets
  (
  PayId int primary key, PayDate date, 
  ProdTotal int, 
  FinalTotal int, 
  PayOrdId int references orders, 
  PayProdId int references Products, 
  PayCustId int references Customers
  );
```

Products table:

```
create table Products (
  ProdId number primary key, 
  ProdNum number not null unique, 
  ProdName varchar2(15), 
  ProdPrice int, 
  ProdQuantity int, 
  ProdCustId int references Customers, 
  ProdOrdId int references Orders, 
  ProdStoreId int references Stores
);
```

Procedure :

```
create procedure FINAL_TOTAL(C IN NUMBER, T OUT NUMBER) IS BEGIN 
UPDATE 
  Payments 
SET 
  FinalTotal = FinalTotal + ProdTotal 
WHERE 
  PayCustId = C;
Commit;
SELECT 
  FinalTotal into T 
FROM 
  Payments 
WHERE 
  PayCustId = C;
END;
/
```

Trigger:

```
create trigger PROD_TOTAL
    AFTER INSERT ON Products
    BEGIN
    UPDATE Paymnets 
    SET ProdTotal = (SELECT Products.ProdPrice * Products.ProdQuantity FROM Products);
    END;
    /
```

insert statement:

```
insert into Payments values(1,'2020-10-07',1,1,1);
```

Well, after inserting this many values I knew that I'll get an error and so I got:

> error:not enough values

Here I want to know, how can I insert the values in the Payment table and If my procedure code is wrong then what should I write? So please help me in solving these issues!!

Comment: That update statement is not corellated back to `Payments` in the subquery `where Products.ProdId = Payments.PayProdId)` But an indexed view may be better for this.

Comment: @Charlieface Sorry, but I didn't get u!

Comment: You have posted an INSERT on Payments, but trigeer is related on INSERT on products table. Another: you'll update every payments with the same value, is right?

Comment: You tagged your question with "sql-server" (Microsoft SQL Server) but the syntax looks like a different DBMS. Add the correct tag and remove "sql-server".

Comment: @JoeTaras The reason why I wrote insert on Products is that ProdPrice and ProdQuantity are there in the Products table so after inserting into the Products table then only I can calculate my total, and I am even sorry that I didn't paste my Procedure code but now I have pasted it so after reading it if u still feel any issue in that code then please let me know.

Comment: If any one of you knows the solution, then please help me!

Comment: The immediate problem is that your `payments` table has 7 column but your `insert` statement is only providing 5 values.  If you specified the columns you wanted to insert into explicitly (which you always should for any insert statement), the statement would be syntactically valid but might not be what you want.  I doubt your trigger is correct but that isn't the immediate cause of the error.

Comment: @JustinYeah, I forgot this Thank you very much!!